# Tetrahedron orientation for triangle meshes

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I have 2 triangles and vertices p0, p1, p2, p3. These two triangle share an edge. From these two triangle I want to make a tetrahedron given by the 4 vertices. The library which I work with requires that "the 4 vertices should be given such that the four vertex triples defining the tetrahedron faces in the drawing appear in counter-clockwise order when being viewed at from the outside" [image: drawing] . Assuming one of the two triangles is p0, p1, p2 I calculate the normal as being (p1-p0) (cross) (p2-p0). Can someone please tell me a way to ensure that this condition is met ?

Comment: It's a shame you went to all the trouble to provide a very clear diagram and then used the wrong labels for the vertices in the text of your question.  The first time I read it I was very confused.

Comment: You would generally need some other way to decide on outside - often this comes from the meshing algorithm (marching cubes etc)

Comment: If both triangles have the normals calculated in the same way as mentioned in the description  couldn't I just pick one side (the one the normal is pointing) and consider it  front or behind?

Comment: Short short answer: yes, as long as you take the points in a consistent order...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer:

The condition is that `p3` must be on the correct side of the plane determined by `(p0, p1, p2)`.

So, after computing the normal for this plane, you need to determine if the vector from (say) `p0` to `p3` is pointing in the same direction of the normal, or the opposite direction, by taking the dot product `dot(normal, p3-p0)`.

---

More mathematically speaking:

You need to find the determinant of the 4x4 matrix formed by the homogeneous coordinates of the four points.  The sign of the determinant determines if the condition is met; the appropriate sign depends on the exact conventions used, but ideally it should be positive:

```
require:
  0 < det(p0, p1, p2, p3)

  == det [ p0.x p0.y p0.z 1 ]
         [ p1.x p1.y p1.z 1 ]
         [ p2.x p2.y p2.z 1 ]
         [ p3.x p3.y p3.z 1 ]
```

If a particular ordered set of points has a negative determinant, you can fix it by swapping any two of the points (which will negate the determinant):

```
e.g., swapping p0 and p2:

det(p0, p1, p2, p3) = - det(p2, p1, p0, p3)
     ^       ^               ^       ^
```

or, more generally, switching between [even and odd permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) of the four vertices.

If the determinant is zero, the four points are co-planar, and cannot be fixed like this.

---

Finally, the code:

A relatively simple way to compute this determinant with 3-d vector math:

```
let:  v1 = p1 - p0
      v2 = p2 - p0
      v3 = p3 - p0
      norm12 = cross(v1, v2)
   -> determinant = dot(norm12, v3)
```

The final determinant is also known as the "triple product" of v1, v2, and v3.

Note that I have hesitated to try to decode the exact sign convention (i.e., whether you need the determinant to be positive or negative) from your question:  the wording and diagram you supply is more than a bit confusing.

Since you have the original library and its documentation, though, you are in the best position to answer this question.  As a last resort, you can try the empirical method: try both signs, and pick the one that doesn't blow up...

Comment: Thank-you so much for the clarifying answer. It worked like a charm